# What does Keras image generators do with input images samplewise_std_normalization= True?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, cnn, normalization, feature-scaling

I have trained a a convolutional network samplewise_std_normalization=True. Now I want to check my model in real-time using Opencv. Therefore I would like to perform the same preprocessing on the input image. Can somebody explain what kind of normalization is perfomed by Keras image generators ?

Answer (score 1):

How to Standardize Image With ImageDataGenerator
Standardization is a data scaling technique that assumes that the distribution of the data is Gaussian and shifts the distribution of the data to have a mean of zero and a standard deviation of one.

Data with this distribution is referred to as a standard Gaussian. It can be beneficial when training neural networks as the dataset sums to zero and the inputs are small values in the rough range of about -3.0 to 3.0 (e.g. 99.7 of the values will fall within three standard deviations of the mean).

Standardization of images is achieved by subtracting the mean pixel value and dividing the result by the standard deviation of the pixel values.

The mean and standard deviation statistics can be calculated on the training dataset, and as discussed in the previous section, Keras refers to this as feature-wise.

```
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True, featurewise_std_normalization=True)
# calculate mean and standard deviation on the training dataset
    datagen.fit(trainX)
```

The statistics can also be calculated then used to standardize each image separately, and Keras refers to this as sample-wise standardization.

```
# sample-wise standardization
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(samplewise_center=True, samplewise_std_normalization=True)
```

I hope this article help you:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-normalize-center-and-standardize-images-with-the-imagedatagenerator-in-keras/